# Is the set $\{2, 3, 4\}$ open in some metric spaces and not open in others?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I just want to check my understanding. This is from Baby Rudin:

> **2.18 Definition** Let $X$ be a metric space. All points and sets mentioned below are understood to be elements and subsets of $X$.
>
> $(a)$ A neighborhood of $p$ is a set $N_r(p)$ consisting of all $q$ such that $d(p, q)<r$ for some $r>0$. The number $r$ is called the *radius* of $N_r( p)$
>
> $(e)$ A point $p$ is an *interior point* of $E$ if there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N \subset E$
>
> $(f)$ $E$ is *open* if every point of $E$ is an interior point of $E$.

Suppose we have the metric space with set $X=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and distance function $d(x, y)=|x-y|$. Now $2$ is an interior point of $\{2, 3, 4\}$ because $N_{0.5}(2)=\{2\} \subset \{2, 3, 4\}$ (and a similar argument can be made for $3$ and $4$ as well.

But if our metric space is $\mathbb{R}$ with the same distance function, then $\{2, 3, 4\}$ is not open because no neighborhood of $2$ is a subset of $\{2, 3, 4\}$, so $2$ is not an interior point of $\{2, 3, 4\}$, right?

Comment: Right.  That's completely correct.

Comment: Why *"no neighborhood of $2$  is a subset of $\{2,3,4\}$"*? You are right, but you need to add some explanation.

Comment: @Krish When we are dealing with the set $\mathbb{R}$, every neighborhood will contain numbers which are not integers.

Comment: @Krish: Because any neighborhood of $2$ (by the definition given) has the form $(2-r,2+r)$ for some $r>0.$ This will readily contain some non-integer rational number.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks!

Comment: @Ovi yes!!! You are absolutely right.

Comment: @Krish  Because a neighborhood of 2 is all the points in R so that $d(2,x) <\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  That is the neighborhood is all reals in $(2-\epsilon, 2+ \epsilon)$ which contains all the numbers between $2-\epsilon$ and $2 +\epsilon$ nearly all of which are not in {2,3,4}

Comment: @CameronBuie sorry!!! But I was just checking whether OP understood the reason clearly or not. (+1) for the question.

Comment: @Krish Thank you for making sure!

Comment: Note, the open sets of toplogies can be defined nearly any way.  The topology $d(x,y) 1\iff x \ne y$ will also make {2,3,4} open. But d(x,y) = |x-y| if both x,y < 2 or x,y > 2, d(2,2) = 0, d(2,x) = |x-2| + 1 if x != 2, and d(x,y) = |x-y| + 2 other wise.  Will make 2 an interior point of ever set containing but 3, and 4 are not interior points of {2,3,4}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely right. Nicely reasoned!

Another thing to consider is that even when the underlying space is the same, using a different metric may yield different open sets. Letting our metric space be $\Bbb R,$ but with the distance function $$\delta(x,y):=\begin{cases}0 & x=y\\1 & x\neq y,\end{cases}$$ we can show that (for example) $\{2\}$ is a neighborhood of $2$ with radius $\frac12,$ and by similar reasoning conclude that $\{2,3,4\}$ is once again open.